# Haskell opposite of intersect (List)

Tags: list, haskell, intersect

I'm trying to get the "opposite" of intersect of two list:
like:

```
let all  = [1..5]
let mask = [2,3]
let res  = ???
-- let res = all `intersect` mask <-- reverse/opposite ?
-- I want to get [1,4,5] ?
```

Comment: I think that's called a relative complement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for *set difference*, which is the `\\` operator from [Data.List](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html#20):

```
Prelude> import Data.List ((\\))
Prelude Data.List> let all  = [1..5]
Prelude Data.List> let mask = [2,3]
Prelude Data.List> all \\ mask
[1,4,5]
```

Comment: @user914584 But be aware that `(\\)` removes only one element from the first list per element of the second, e.g. `[1,2,3,2] \\ [2] = [1,3,2]`. If that's not good for your use case, ``filter (`notElem` second) first`` is an alternative.